# Can I use a SP designer 2013 web part page in SP 2013 online?

Tags: web-parts, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I'm using SP 2013 online and SP designer 2013 to manage on the background.

In SP designer 2010 I'm able to create a web part page

-> Site objects -> Site pages -> Ribbon -> Web part page

When I have created such page I see now possibility to use that in SP 2013 online.
I think this is because you can freely adjust and design the webparts in the frontend of SP 2013 but I'm not sure.

Can anyone confirm this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample screenshot to create web part page in SharePoint online with SharePoint designer 2013.

While SharePoint online provide modern page which supports similar functionality.
[image]

[image]

Comment: can you tell me than how apply the aspx file created in designer (first picture) in the front environment (second picture).
I can't figure out how that works.